# Sort by multiple columns but different crietria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table in SQL SERVER from which i want to select the records using order by but i am having different scenario. Please have a look at below table.

```
EmployeeCode | EmployeeArea
    001      |     8568
    002      |     4549
    004      |     4549
    005      |     8568
    003      |     4549
    006      |     7777
    010      |     4549
    007      |     8568
    008      |     7777
    009      |     4549
```

As shown above i have two fields Employee Code and Employee Area. Now, What i want to do is Sort Records by Employee Codes first and then EmployeeArea but not in standard Way. Please see below desired o/p for better understanding

```
  EmployeeCode   | EmployeeArea
        001      |     8568
        005      |     8568
        007      |     8568
        002      |     4549
        003      |     4549
        004      |     4549
        009      |     4549
        010      |     4549
        006      |     7777
        008      |     7777
```

As shown above first sort is on employeeCode and according to that, first employee(ex 001)'s Employee Area(8568) all employees with areacode 01 will be placed together and it will placed in asc order by employee code.
I tired using multiple ways like group by, CTE, temporary tables but cant get desired output. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would make the example better if Emp 001 wouldn't have Area 01 but higher, so I would say mix up the numbers a little bit.

Comment: Updated as asked.

Comment: Larnu, If you check the data closely, i specifically need to sort on EmployeeCode first as first priority is EmployeeCode and then EmployeeArea. Because i want to order the data EmployeeCode Wise only.

Comment: @Niks my (now deleted) comment was made *before* you completely changed the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like what you need is a windowed `MIN` in the `ORDER BY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('001',8568),
            ('002',4549),
            ('004',4549),
            ('005',8568),
            ('003',4549),
            ('006',7777),
            ('010',4549),
            ('007',8568),
            ('008',7777),
            ('009',4549))V(EmployeeCode,EmployeeArea)
ORDER BY MIN(EmployeeCode) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeArea),
         EmployeeCode,
         EmployeeArea;
```

Comment: Excellent. I had not tried this. This seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you need just order by both columns:

```
SELECT EmplyeeCode, EmplyeeArea
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY EmplyeeArea, EmplyeeCode
```

Here I created demo on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9a2f2f732deb2e0fa1cce9b63092e71). Output is just like you desire.

Comment: Marko, Thanks for answer but i have updated the question to understand better. If you can see, first sorting on EmployeeArea will not work.